# Why is Backbone.Controller undefined even when Backbone is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm trying to add controller to my Todo list app. Here's the code.

```
$(function(){
alert(Backbone); // => [object]
alert(Backbone.Controller); // => undefined
TodoList.Controllers.Todos = Backbone.Controller.extend({
routes: {
    "documents/:id": "edit",
    "": "index",
    "new": "newDoc"
},

edit: function(id){
    var todo = new Todo({id:id});   
    todo.fetch({
        success:function(model,resp){
            new App.Views.Edit({model:todo});
        },
        error: function(){
            new Error({message: "Couldn't find the todo item."});
            window.location.hash = '#';
        }
    });
},

index: function(){
    window.App = new TodoList.Views.AppView
}

});
});
```

As mentioned in the comment, when I alert(Backbone), [object] is returned, while Backbone.Controller returns undefined and I can't figure out why. This is stopping the whole app to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been replaced with Backbone Router: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/

Answer (score 2):

which backbone version do you have?
Try `Backbone.Router` instead of `Backbone.Controller`.
Quote from http://backbonejs.org : as of v5.0

> Controller was renamed to Router, for clarity

If that's the case, you can make a reference copy of the `Router` in order to not alter the existing code :

```
if(Backbone.Router)
    Backbone.controller = Backbone.Router;
```

Comment: I'm using the one provided with gem rails-backbone (codebrew). Previously I had problem with "refresh" event changed to "reset". Had it not been for StackOverflow, this would have taken days. A whole hearted thank you. Means a lot.